# Python 3.x : move to next line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a small script that is extracting some text from a .html file.

```
f = open(local_file,"r")
for line in f:
    searchphrase = '<span class="position'
    if searchphrase in line:
        print("found it\n")
```

That works fine for me(error handling will be imported later), my problem is that the text I want to extract follows 2 lines after the searchphrase. How can I move 2 lines down in the .html file ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can advance `f` (which is an iterable) by two lines by calling [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on it twice:

```
with open(local_file,"r") as f
    for line in f:
        searchphrase = '<span class="position'
        if searchphrase in line:
            print("found it\n")
            next(f) # skip 1 line
            return next(f)  # and return the line after that.
```

*However*, if you are trying to parse HTML, consider using a HTML parser *instead*. Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

This works nice for me:

```
f = open(local_file,"r")
found = -1
for line in f:
    if found == 2:
        print("Line: "+line);
        break
    elif found > 0:
        found += 1
    else:
        searchphrase = '<span class="position'
        if searchphrase in line:
            print("found it")
            found = 1
```

The input file was:

```
bla
<span class="position">Hello</span>
blub
that's it
whatever
```

And the output of the program:

```
found it
Line: that's it
```

Instead of calling `break` you may also reset `found` to -1 to search for more occurences of the pattern...