# read next line after a matching line in python

Tags: python-3.4

I am trying to go to next line after a match in python. I have a file:

```
ratio of lattice parameters  b/a  c/a
    1.000000000000    1.000000000000
lattice parameters  a b c  [a.u.] 
    9.448629942895    9.448629942895    9.448629942895
```

So, when I have `"lattice parameters"` at the beginning of line, I will read the next line (e.g.  `9.448629942895    9.448629942895    9.448629942895`)
I am doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

inpf = str(sys.argv[1])
print (inpf)
with open(inpf, "r") as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        if line.startswith("lattice parameters"):
            print(line.strip())
            next(ifile)
            return next(ifile)
```

as is in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656817/python-3-x-move-to-next-line).
But, in my case, it is giving error:

```
python xband.py AlSi2S2.sys 
  File "xband.py", line 11
    return next(ifile)
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

What I am doing wrong here?
**NB:** I want to go to and read next line. I have no special fascination on "return"
I am using `Python 3.4.2`

Comment: Well you're using return outside of a function, which is not allowed in Python. Wrap your code in a function like `def getLine(...):` and it's gonna be fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
with open(inpf, "r") as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        if line.startswith("lattice parameters"):
            print(next(ifile, '').strip())
```

> *next(iterator[, default])*
>  Retrieve the next item from the iterator by
>   calling its **next**() method. If default is given, it is returned if
>   the iterator is exhausted, otherwise *StopIteration* is raised.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a return statement outside of a function. For the code to work you schould either get rid of the `return next(ifile)` line or make a function in your script and call it.